# batch file to delete all files in a folder with special character

Tags: wordpress, batch-file

i need a batch file that can delete all files in a folder that have a dash ('-') in them. Note they are image files so they can be be png or jpeg, etc.. any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the following code to your preferences.

```
@echo off
cd /d "LocationOfItems"
echo Deleting all items with "-"...
del *-*
echo Completed.
pause
```

Wildcards allow for variation on either end of the string. File type is optional. In this example, it doesn't need to be specified because they are different (jpg, png, etc).

Comment: so i place this in the folder with all images? also replace location with the folder location on pc obviously? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, replace the 'LocationOfItems' with the path of the folder.

Comment: will try it out.. Thanks!

Comment: I'd add the `/D` switch to `cd` to avoid trouble when the desired items are not located on the current drive...

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$dir = "img";//folder url which consist file to delete. you can use wordpress file location using wordpress function 
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
if (strpos($filename,'_') !== false)//check whether it conist of '_'
{
unlink('img/'.$filename);//remove file from folder
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: i was actually thinking php would be better.. so i just upload this and visit it and script will run?